# Запрет просмотра каталогов кроме домашнего

Tags: sftp

Всем добрый день. Прошу помощи у вас. Мне нужно создать нового пользователя. И разрешить ему просмотр/чтение/запись ТОЛЬКО в домашнем каталоге. Остальные от него скрыть. Так сказать - запретить выход из домашнего каталога.

Уточню ещё, что всё это происходит через SFTP

ОС - Centos 6.4

Answer (score -1):

думаю это решение вам поможет: [How to Setup Chroot SFTP in Linux (Allow Only SFTP, not SSH)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/)

Comment: что-то не пойму как настраивать.

Comment: с английским совсем плохо?

Comment: Вот что пишет при попытке входа на сервер - http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1202/b6/8b8fb6cd9c98349d23981c33d6f89db6.png